# NSInputStream returned nil for file stored in local documents directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, csv, nsinputstream

I am trying to parse the contents of a downloaded CSV File. The file is stored in a folder in Local Documents Directory.

Filepath: **/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C04089B6-4B9F-4F3A-A7C4-82225024CBE4/data/Containers/Data/Application/7412C7C6-71C7-47FE-810B-965116A6071C/Documents/rndftp/99999920150415152101.csv**

I am using this method to create a NSInputStream :

```
- (instancetype)initWithContentsOfDelimitedURL:(NSURL *)URL delimiter:(unichar)delimiter {
NSInputStream *stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithURL:URL];
return [self initWithInputStream:stream usedEncoding:NULL delimiter:delimiter];
}
```

Here, **URL is [NSURL URLWithString: filepath]** but for this, **stream** is coming as nil.

Thus, it is crashing here:

```
CHCSVParser *parser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
        [parser parse];
NSArray *latestFileComponentsArray = [NSArray     arrayWithContentsOfCSVURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
```

with the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: stream'
```

**What can be the possible reason for the same?** I am using CHCSVParser open source for parsing the csv file.

Answer (score 4):

My bad, There is a small caveat here: If the file is locally downloaded, we specify the URL as **fileURLwithPath**: and not URLWithString: , so the code that is causing the error can be rectified as:

```
CHCSVParser *parser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
        [parser parse];
        NSArray *latestFileComponentsArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
```